# Are Intel x86_64 processors not only pipelined architecture, but also superscalar?

Tags: x86, cpu, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture

Are Intel x86_64 processors not only pipelined architecture, but also superscalar?

1. **Pipelining** - these two sequences execute in parallel (different stages of the same pipeline-unit in the same clock, for example ADD with 4 stages):

   - stage1 -> stage2 -> stage3 -> stage4 -> nothing
   - nothing -> stage1 -> stage2 -> stage3 -> stage4
2. **Superscalar** - these two sequences execute in parallel (two instructions can be launched to different pipeline-units in the same clock, for example ADD and MUL):

   - ADD(stage1) -> ADD(stage2) -> ADD(stage3)
   - MUL(stage1) -> MUL(stage2) -> MUL(stage3)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_CPU_microarchitectures

Comment: How does this relate to programming? Anyway it can easily be found within the first results of ["superscalar"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar): "The P5 Pentium was the first superscalar x86 processor"

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Optimization of performance for superscalar has its own style of code. Yes, I see that for example modern CPU Intel Core has 4 Instruction Decoders: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_(microarchitecture)#mediaviewer/File:Intel_Core2_arch.svg

Comment: Should be migrated to cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, contemporary Intel processors are both *pipelined* and *superscalar*.

It takes many nanoseconds to execute a single instruction. That includes fetching the instruction from the instruction memory, decoding the instruction, fetching the operands, performing any computations, fetching data from memory, and writing the results.  For even basic performance it is important to break these into small steps and allow multiple instructions to be "in the pipeline" simultaneously.

Likewise, a processor pipeline consumes a lot of resources (area, power, design complexity, etc.).  It is relatively very cheap to turn a 1-wide processor into a 2-wide, superscalar processor.  The performance improvement is greater than the costs (although once you have a 4-wide processor, you will see diminishing returns going wider, and the costs grow exponentially).

Thus, you can expect any modern processor (except the absolutely smallest of the small) to be superscalar. Rule of thumb - if it's connected to a memory hierarchy, it will be superscalar. That's because the memory hierarchy consumes so much power and energy that you need a superscalar processor to keep it busy.

Comment: Thank you! "*(although once you have a 4-wide processor, you will see diminishing returns going wider, and the costs grow exponentially)*" - do you mean that growing costs of instruction reordering (requre more time to determine independence of instructions for their simultaneous execution)? Or do you mean that growing complexity of the source code (require more dificult source code for the independent execution of instructions - for example rewrite source code of algorithm `prefix_sum()`/`scan()`/`inclusive_scan()` for simultaneous parallel execution)?

Comment: The costs in terms of the area and energy of the processor. Although yes, also the complexity of the design too, which means the costs to implement and verify more complicated designs that are more likely to have bugs goes up.

Comment: Not only are all major x86 processors superscalar, they're also out-of-order execution.  (Atom is in-order 2-wide superscalar, but the newer Silvermont is OOO.  I forget about AMD's low-power bobcat/jaguar.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.
After some googling i found [this](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/)

Comment: Your answer is *yes*, but you link to a quite extensive document. Can you elaborate a bit more? I understand that the question is not very inviting to write much.

Comment: Yes, that is a good article. But that is TOO OLD! 17 years ago. In this area, 17 years means 2 or 3 generation. If you born a baby when the article was written, the baby is now old enough to go to college to learn how CPU is working nowadays (true only in top 20 universities).

Comment: Hm, the article's last update was Jun 2015. It's pretty fresh material.